# Cron Job linux to start the services in order

Tags: bash, cron, sh, centos7

I have 3 services to be started in the system reboot in a sequnece

Tried blow in crontab -e but no use

```
@reboot sleep 10 && bash /myfolder/hazelcast-x.x/bin/start.sh
@reboot sleep 20 && /myfolder/apache-activemq-x.x/bin/activemq start
@reboot sleep 30 && bash /myfolder/apache-tomcat-x.x/bin/startup.sh
```

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, your statement "no use" is of no use in describing an actual problem. Please give actual observations, not just your interpretation. Also, make sure you checked logfiles to get further info on what's going on, perhaps that already solves your problem. Lastly, what parts are actually necessary? Is it cron, the POSIX shell `sh` or Bash? Make sure you reduce your attempts to a [mcve], because that again helps understanding and fixing the issue yourself.

Comment: You should use a systemd configuration to start services, not crontab.

Answer (score 1):

in your cron command you can use `&&` so if the command on the left hand side fails, the  command on the right hand side will not run. for example,

`command 1 && command 2 && command 3`

Answer (score 0):

Also be aware that the unmodified version of bash /myfolder/hazelcast-x.x/bin/start.sh looks for a pid file if found it will not start. So you may want to clean up the pid file prior to running start.sh after a reboot. We do this to prevent more than one node from starting on a given server since without partition groups that could lead to data loss.